# Resulting MTLTexture lighter than CGImage

Tags: swift, textures, metal, metalkit

I have kernel func which must convert Y and CbCr textures created from pixelBuffer(ARFrame.capturedImage) to RGB texture like in apple guide https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/displaying_an_ar_experience_with_metal
But I get over lighted texture

```
kernel void renderTexture(texture2d<float, access::sample> capturedImageTextureY [[ texture(0) ]],
                          texture2d<float, access::sample> capturedImageTextureCbCr [[ texture(1) ]],
                      
                          texture2d<float, access::read_write> outTextue [[texture(2)]],
                      
                      
                          uint2 size [[threads_per_grid]],
                          uint2 pid [[thread_position_in_grid]]){


constexpr sampler colorSampler(mip_filter::linear,
                               mag_filter::linear,
                               min_filter::linear);


const float4x4 ycbcrToRGBTransform = float4x4(
    float4(+1.0000f, +1.0000f, +1.0000f, +0.0000f),
    float4(+0.0000f, -0.3441f, +1.7720f, +0.0000f),
    float4(+1.4020f, -0.7141f, +0.0000f, +0.0000f),
    float4(-0.7010f, +0.5291f, -0.8860f, +1.0000f)
);

float2 texCoord;
texCoord.x = float(pid.x) / size.x;
texCoord.y = float(pid.y) / size.y;

// Sample Y and CbCr textures to get the YCbCr color at the given texture coordinate
float4 ycbcr = float4(capturedImageTextureY.sample(colorSampler,    texCoord).r,
                      capturedImageTextureCbCr.sample(colorSampler, texCoord).rg, 1.0);

float4 color = ycbcrToRGBTransform * ycbcr;

outTextue.write(color, pid);
```

}

I create CGImage with this code:

```
var cgImage: CGImage?
VTCreateCGImageFromCVPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer, options: nil, imageOut: &cgImage)
```

cgImage has normal lightning

when I try to create texture from cgImage with MTKTextureLoader I get over lighted texture too

How to get MTLTexture with normal light like in cgImage

**cgImage:** (expected result)

[image]

**kernel func:**

create texture with this code:

```
let descriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor()
descriptor.width = Int(Self.maxTextureSize.width)
descriptor.height = Int(Self.maxTextureSize.height)
descriptor.usage = [.shaderWrite, .shaderRead]
    
let texture = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()?.makeTexture(descriptor: descriptor)
```

and write pixels with kernel func.

already tried different pixelFormats of MTLTextureDescriptor

[image]

**textureLoader:**

```
let textureLoader = MTKTextureLoader(device: MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!)
let texturee = try! textureLoader.newTexture(cgImage: cgImage!, options: [.SRGB : (false as NSNumber)])
```

already tried different MTKTextureLoader.Options

[image]

**GitHub project demonstrating issue:** [PixelBufferToMTLTexture](https://github.com/piroznoe/PixelBufferToMTLTexture)

Comment: With these examples it's hard to understand what the problem is, try to upload a minimal project to GitHub.

Comment: What is your iPhone model?

Comment: iPad Pro 4th gen 12.9, Iphone XS

Comment: it seems like scene kit adds additional gamma correction to your texture

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 But why scene kit don't add it for MTLTexture created form textureLoader.newTexture(with: data, ...   Like in your answer

Comment: You can solve this problem by adding a gamma correction equation to your shader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was solved Thanks 0xBFE1A8, by adding gamma correction

by replacing

`outTextue.write(color, pid);`

with:

```
outTextue.write(float4(pow(color.rgb, float3(2,2,2)), color.a), pid);
```

Answer (score 4):

> when I try to create texture from cgImage with MTKTextureLoader I get
> over lighted texture

It's because metal applies gamma correction to your texture.

[MTKTextureLoader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalkit/mtktextureloader/option/1536032-srgb) has an **SRGB** key that is used to specify whether the texture data is stored as sRGB image data.

> If the value is false, the image data is treated as linear pixel data.
> If the value is true, the image data is treated as sRGB pixel data. If
> this key is not specified and the image being loaded has been
> gamma-corrected, the image data uses the specified sRGB information.

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "yourTexture", ofType: "png")!
let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) as! Data
let texture = try! textureLoader.newTexture(with: data, options: [MTKTextureLoaderOptionSRGB : (false as NSNumber)])
```

---

**You can also solve this problem by adding a [gamma correcting equation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_performance/ci_performance.html) to your shader.**

- Linear to sRGB and vice versa:

`rgb = mix(rgb.0.0774, pow(rgb*0.9479 + 0.05213, 2.4), step(0.04045, rgb))`

`rgb = mix(rgb12.92, pow(rgb*0.4167) * 1.055 - 0.055, step(0.00313, rgb))`

Comment: Thanks for answer, But MTKTextureLoader.Option.SRGB option works for me only when I create texture form path/name, but when I create it from cgImage it did not

Comment: When I use this conversion a get little bit other color but too close. But when I use code provided in my answer I get color 1:1.