# Metal Output texture/image itself is lighter than input image

Tags: image, textures, metal

I have a method that converts an output texture to a CIImage, turns that into a rep that is attached to an NSImage. This image is then drawn into a much larger canvas image (also NSImage) - around the mouse point. This works fine with kernels that generate color patterns to the output texture, etc. The problem is when a kernel uses an input texture, the output result is ‘whitened’/duller, even when the kernel simply copies the input texture to the output texture. So I assume that the problem is somewhere in the transition from NSImage to a metal texture.

The input image is a 64 x 64 NSImage that I draw a larger composition image into (with offset). I then translate this image into a CGImage and that into a metal texture.

```
NSSize  theSize;
theSize.height = (int)[passedImage size].height;
theSize.width = (int)[passedImage size].width;

CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)[passedImage TIFFRepresentation], NULL);
CGImageRef maskRef =  CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);

MTLTextureDescriptor*   textureDescriptor;
    textureDescriptor = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat: MTLPixelFormatRGBA8Unorm
                                                                           width: (int)theSize.width * 2
                                                                          height: (int)theSize.height * 2
                                                                       mipmapped: YES];
}
textureDescriptor.usage = MTLTextureUsageShaderWrite | MTLTextureUsageShaderRead;
id<MTLTexture> inputTexture = [textureLoader newTextureWithCGImage: maskRef options: nil error: NULL];
id<MTLTexture> outputTexture = [device newTextureWithDescriptor: textureDescriptor];
MTLSize threadgroupCount = MTLSizeMake(8, 8, 1);
MTLSize threadgroups = MTLSizeMake((int)theSize.width * 2, (int)theSize.height * 2, 1);
[commandEncoder dispatchThreadgroups: threadgroups threadsPerThreadgroup: threadgroupCount];
```

Note that this code works in another program that uses the much larger “composition” image as the input texture - without having to “double” the size and isn’t whitened. The only other differences in the two programs is that the canvas image, rather than being passed in is retrieved:

```
CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)[[[theAppD theView]layerImage]TIFFRepresentation], NULL);
```

and the output converted back to an NSImage rather than being drawn into the canvas image is set as the canvas image: [[theAppD theView]setLayerImage: resultImage];

Comment: Welcome! Can you please try passing the following options to `newTextureWithCGImage`? `@{MTKTextureLoaderOptionSRGB: [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]}` (Also try passing `YES` instead. I'm assuming that the gamma curve of one of the images is off.)

Comment: @FrankSchlegel Thanks for responding. I added suggestion in options dictionary with no noticeable effect with either value.

Comment: @FrankSchlegel  Also tried CGImageCreateCopyWithColorSpace passing kCGColorSpaceGenericRGBLinear as theCGImage color space. No change.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in a similar post at [Resulting MTLTexture lighter than CGImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62478638/resulting-mtltexture-lighter-than-cgimage) after reading @FrankSchlege gamma comment (thanks).
I changed the code for writing my output texture from this:

outTexture.write(float4(colorAtPixel), gid);

to this:

```
 outTexture.write(float4(pow(colorAtPixel.rgb, float3(2,2,2)), colorAtPixel.a), gid);
```

This gets a very close match.
Since both of these questions (mine and the above post) were using a cgImage I thought the problem was with cgImage. Having now added the standard Mac color picker  to the program and I am just drawing with the passed in color, I found that the colors don’t exactly match the picker. The above pow function corrected this as well.

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_performance/ci_performance.html